# How do you rename a branch in CVS?

Tags: cvs

If you've named a branch in CVS incorrectly, or the name originally chosen becomes inappropriate, how do you change it to something else?

A related question is [How do you rename a branch in CVS without admin access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299015/how-do-you-rename-a-branch-in-cvs-without-admin-access).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick to this is using one of CVSs' more obscure admin commands, -N.  It is a two stage process, effectively copy then remove.

Firstly, you create a branch with the correct name that references the original branch name.  Secondly, you delete the original branch name.

Assume you have a file "File.txt" that is currently branched "bad`_`branch".  You'd like the branch to be called - can you guess? - "good`_`branch".

> kwutchak% cvs log File.txt
>
> RCS file: .../data/File.txt,v
> head: 1.1
> branch:
> symbolic names:
> bad`_`branch: 1.1.0.2

### To create the new branch reference:

```
cvs admin -N good_branch:bad_branch File.txt
```

> kwutchak% cvs log File.txt
>
> RCS file: .../data/File.txt,v
> Working file: File.txt
> head: 1.1
> branch:
> symbolic names:
> good`_`branch: 1.1.0.2
> bad`_`branch: 1.1.0.2

```
Bonus Tip:

A symbolic name is not always required with `-N`.  It is sometimes
valid to use a numeric reference to the branch (as when one may have
used `cvs admin -N` and accidentally deleted the branch name by running 
a delete command like `cvs admin -N bad_branch` when there is no
other name assigned yet.  The following command worked to add a name
to a branch (that contained only one file) and the file no longer had
a branch name associated with it:

    cvs admin -N good_branch:1.1.2.1 File.txt
```

### To delete the original reference:

```
cvs admin -N bad_branch File.txt
```

> kwutchak% cvs log File.txt
>
> RCS file: .../data/File.txt,v
> Working file: File.txt
> head: 1.1
> branch:
> symbolic names:
> good`_`branch: 1.1.0.2

Comment: Please excuse me for accepting my own answer - I'm using StackOverflow as a record so that I don't need to research this again in future...

Comment: Many people use it for the same purpose, until you add something useful to the whole community you're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you made a mistake "a few branches ago", admin -N option won't be helpful due to the branch position change.

This solution will work only with full access to repository of Your project.

1. Go to CVSROOT/Project
2. Create a backup copy
3. grep "old-branch-name" * -rl | xargs sed -i 's/old-branch-name/new-branch-name/g'

Worked like a charm for me.

Sorry for necro, but I think that my solution will help anyone with situation similiar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot add comments to given answers yet (reputation to low), I want to remark that the given command in previous answer is missing double-quotes!

Correction:

```
grep "old-branch-name" * -rl | xargs sed -i 's/old-branch-name/new-branch-name/g'
```